# Ubuntu 18.04 BionicでCaboCha0.69のコンパイル時にエラーが出ます

Tags: ubuntu, cabocha

CaboChaのインストールに当たって、
１．MeCabが動いていることは、「すもも」テストで検証済み
２．CRF++はインストール済み
３．CaboChaをダウンロードしてコンパイルしようとすると以下のエラーが出ます

```
morph.cpp:6:10: fatal error: mecab.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mecab.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:597: recipe for target 'morph.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [morph.lo] Error 1
```

コンパイラを使うのが初めてなので、エラーの意味が分からず対処の方法がとりえませんので、教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 余談ですが、Ubuntuのコードネーム"Bionic Beaver"を略すのであれば"Bionic"の方が通じやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MeCabをUbuntuのパッケージマネージャ(aptコマンド)経由でインストールした場合には、**libmecab-dev**パッケージを追加でインストールしてみてください。

表示されているコンパイル時のエラー、`mecab.h: No such file or directory`は「必要なヘッダファイルが見つからない」という内容ですが、このファイルはMeCab本体とは別のパッケージに含まれています。

```
$ sudo apt search mecab
p   libmecab-dev     - Header files of Mecab
p   mecab            - Japanese morphological analysis system
```

[bionic の amd64 アーキテクチャ用 libmecab-dev パッケージのファイル一覧](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ja/bionic/amd64/libmecab-dev/filelist)

> /usr/bin/mecab-config
>   /usr/include/mecab.h
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmecab.a
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmecab.so
>   /usr/share/doc/libmecab-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
>   /usr/share/doc/libmecab-dev/copyright
>   /usr/share/man/man1/mecab-config.1.gz

Comment: cubickさんに教えていただいた方法（libmecab-devの追加インストール）でエラーは解決しました。まだ他の問題が出てきますが調べた上でまたご相談します。